# How to count words in url

Tags: unix, awk, sed, grep

I'm given a data set which contain several url like:

```
http://dbpedia.org/resource/Duncan_Trussell
http://dbpedia.org/resource/Ruth_Mary_Reynolds
http://dbpedia.org/resource/Abbas_Noyan
http://dbpedia.org/resource/John_E._Dowdell
http://dbpedia.org/resource/John_F._Du
```

Basically, i needed to make a script which shows the name of the people, the result should be like this:

```
First name
John 2
Abbas 1
Duncan 1
Ruth 1

Last Name
Trussels 1
Reynolds 1
Noyan 1
Dowdell 1
Du 1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
grep -Po 'resource/\K[^_]*(?=_)' urls.txt | uniq -c | awk '{print $2" "$1}'
```

Output:

```
Duncan 1
Ruth 1
Abbas 1
John 2
```

---

```
grep -Po '_\K[^_]*$' urls.txt | uniq -c | awk '{print $2" "$1}'
```

Output:

```
Trussell 1
Reynolds 1
Noyan 1
Dowdell 1
Du 1
```

---

If you want you can replace `| uniq -c | awk '{print $2" "$1}'` by `| awk '{count[$1]++}END{for(j in count) print j, count[j]}'`.

Comment: Hi, this doesn't work for me, do you need a certain version of grep ?

Comment: @Jidder: I used GNU grep 2.6.3.

Comment: I have `(GNU grep) 2.5.1`, guessing it doesn't support something :(

Answer (score 0):

All in awk
Split the last field on `_`
Increment the first and last fields of the split using associative array
Then at the end just print the names and their respective counts.

```
awk -F/ '{t=split($NF,a,"_");b[a[1]]++;c[a[t]]++}
         END{print "Firstnames";for(i in b)print i,b[i]
             print "\nLastnames";for(j in c) print j,c[j]
          }' test
```

#### output

```
Firstnames
Duncan 1
Ruth 1
John 2
Abbas 1

Lastnames
Noyan 1
Du 1
Trussell 1
Reynolds 1
Dowdell 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is another `awk`

```
awk -F"/|_" '{a[$5]++;b[$NF]++} END {for (i in a) print i,a[i];print "";for (i in b) print i,b[i]}' file
Duncan 1
Ruth 1
John 2
Abbas 1

Noyan 1
Du 1
Trussell 1
Reynolds 1
Dowdell 1
```

This should be much faster than the multiple command `grep` `uniq` `awk`

Answer (score 0):

With GNU awk for true 2-D arrays:

```
$ gawk -F'/' '
{
    nr = split($NF,names,/_/)
    cnt["First"][names[1]]++
    cnt["Last"][names[nr]]++
}
END {
    for (pos in cnt) {
        print pos, "name"
        for (name in cnt[pos]) {
            print name, cnt[pos][name]
        }
    }
}
' file
Last name
Noyan 1
Du 1
Trussell 1
Reynolds 1
Dowdell 1
First name
Duncan 1
Ruth 1
John 2
Abbas 1
```